# Reference resource in terraform sub module

Tags: terraform

I'm in the process of converting a legacy aws setup into Terraform and have the following:

```
ci
  - main.tf
ci/worker
    - main.tf
```

In ci I have an aws security group which I want to reference in my submodules.  Currently I have:

```
vpc_security_group_ids      = ["${aws_security_group.vpc-idhere.id}"]
```

Which errors with:

```
A managed resource "aws_security_group" "vpc-idhere" has not been declared in ci-workers.
```

The security group is defined in ci/main.tf

How do I correctly reference a resource in a sub module?

Answer (score 0):

When calling across module boundaries you need to use variables/outputs to pass references to resources; modules can't peek inside other modules.

So your `ci-workers` module will need to declare an input variable such as:

```
variable "vpc_security_group_ids" {
  description = "List of VPC security group IDs"
  type        = list
}
```

You then use `${var.vpc_security_group_ids}` within the module. Then when you instantiate this module, you can pass in the IDs from the parent:

```
module "ci-workers" {
  source                 = "..."
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.vpc-idhere.id}"]
}
```

See the [module documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html) for more information.